# CakePHP - Site Offline - Admin Routing Not Working

Tags: cakephp, admin, authentication

I setup the following code in my `app_controllers.php` file to control access to the site when the site is set to OFFLINE (site_status = 0).

```
function beforeFilter(){
    // Site Offline = 0 , Site Online = 1
    if($this->Configuration->get_site_status() == 1){
          // Allow access to the site to all users and perform all required 
          // beforeFilter code
    }else{
        ...
        // If site is OFFLINE but User is logged in allow access. 
        // Later I will need to change it to only allow admin access if logged in as I am still developing
        // Everyone else will be denied access even if they are able to authenticate          
        if(!$this->Auth->user() == null){
            $this->layout = 'default';
            $this->Auth->allow('*');
        }else{        
            $this->layout = 'offline';
            $this->Auth->deny('*');
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Everything works great when the requested address looks like the following:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/articles
```

However, when I have the following it does not work properly

```
http://www.mydomain.com/admin/articles
```

It prevents access to the site correctly, but it fails to use the `$this->layout = 'offline'`. It defaults back to the `default` layout.

What do I need to do to fix this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing that looks out of place to me is:

```
(!$this->Auth->user() == null)
```

This looks very wrong and might be causing your problems.  I would suggest changing this to something like:

```
(!is_null($this->Auth->user())
```

or

```
($this->Auth->user() !== NULL)
```

**Edits**

[First, check out the PHP logical operators](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).  You were appending a `NOT` statement to the return value of `$this->Auth->user()`.  So, with a user logged in you're essentially asking if `false` is equal to `null`, which of course it isn't and never will be.

[Second, check out the PHP comparison operators](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).  You aren't wanting to check if the *value* of `$this->Auth->user()`  is equal to the value `null`, you're wanting to check if the *data type* of `$this->Auth->user()` is equal to the *type* `null`.  In short, [`null` is a data type, not a value](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php).  If you did just have to use "=" in your if statement then you would want to use the identical `===` check or the identical not check `!==`.

Comment: I thought all these expressions including the one in my code represented the same thing. Regardless, I've tried your first suggestion `!is_null($this->Auth->user())` and my code is still behaving the same. I believe it is how Auth is handling the admin routing prefix, but do not know how to fix it. Do you have anymore suggestion.

Comment: @CaboONE I have to go to work.  If nobody has answered you by the time I get off I will expand on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` conditions look weird. They are:

```
If site is offline and user logged in
    use default layout
otherwise
    use offline layout and require authentication on all pages
```

I.e. you're using offline layout when site is online OR user is not logged in. Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: I will post more code in my question shortly but, the idea is to show the site as offline to all unauthenticated users. However, if the site is marked as offline, but the user is authenticated, then we make the site available. I have not fully implement ACL yet, but the idea is to allow ADMINs to access the site even if it is OFFLINE.