# Redirect to maintenance page in CakePHP doesn't work

Tags: cakephp, error-handling

I am trying to set a maintenance page so that when the site is disabled, it should appear no matter what page was requested.

I currently tried doing this with `$this->cakeError()`:

in `app_controller.php`:

```
function beforeFilter(){
....
if($this->__get_config('maintenance_status') == 1){
        $this->cakeError('maintenance', array('message' => $this->__get_config('maintenance_message')));    
    }
....
}
```

and in `app_error.php`:

```
function maintenance($message){
    $this->controller->set('message', $message['message']); 
    ($this->controller->RequestHandler->isAjax()) ? $this->_outputMessage('ajax_maintenance') : $this->_outputMessage('maintenance');
}
```

The problem is that a Fatal Error occurs, which says: `Call to a member function isAjax() on a non-object`. But I have obviously set the `RequestHandler` Component in `app_controller.php`. Moreover, I have tried calling this error from within another controller and it doesn't give me any Fatal Error.

What could be the problem? Why doesn't it recognize that I have initalized the Component?

Comment: Where exactly in `AppController` is the error being called?

Comment: In the `beforeFilter()` method. I have edited my post to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

[From the CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1188/Error-Handling):

> Calling this method will show an error page to the user and halt any further processing in your application

**I am assuming that you're calling the error in some callback in `AppController`.**

If that is the case you may very likely be halting execution of your script before your components are instantiated.  This would certainly cause your error.

Now, I think this error is a good chance to reevaluate how you're dealing with the problem.  Is this really an error?  You know the maintenance status is set so it's **expected** that the user be shown this page.  It isn't an error.  Furthermore, you certainly wouldn't want 10,000 messages in your log telling you that you turned maintenance on!

I think this could be better solved by utilizing some controller callbacks and a little bit of code.

**I don't know what _get_config() is so I assume it is a custom user function that you can call in this callback.**

We'll be using the [`beforeFilter()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/984/Callbacks) controller callback.

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        if ($this->_get_config('maintenance_status') === 1) {
            $this->redirect('/maintenance');
        }
    }

}
```

Now, you can just setup a maintenance controller, attached to its own view, that will properly show your maintenance message, and won't log all those connection attempts during maintenance in your error log.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is the way I've tried before and it didn't work, that's why my second attempt was with `cakeError()`. In my first attempt I have created a `MaintenanceController`, added a `maintenance()` method, and created its view, `maintenance.ctp`. Then, in `app_controller.php`, in the `beforeFilter()` method I have added: `if($this->__get_config('maintenance_status') == 1){
   $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'maintenance', 'action' => 'maintenance')); 
  }` but my browser informs me that `The page isn't redirecting properly` and I don't know why.

Comment: Are there any errors in your error_log for why the redirect isn't working?  Are you sure you have your `maintenance.ctp` in the proper `maintenance` dir inside `views`?

Comment: Normally you'll find this in your OS log directory.  For example, on my Mac running apache2 my error_log is at `/private/var/log/apache2/error_log`.

Comment: Nope, nothing useful there...But anyway, why it should redirect continuously in a loop? It simply redirects to that specific action in the `MaintenanceController` and that's that. Why does it keep redirecting?

Comment: Not sure, you should ask a new question showing some code where the redirect is being called and some info on what OS you're using.

Comment: I filtered the redirect to take place only when the page is not the maintenance page itself. But it seems that when it redirects to the maintenance page, it checks the current controller, which surprisingly is not `MaintenanceController`, but another controller which is included via an element in my main menu. Basically the `$this->params['controller']` or `$this->here` returns in first place that controller from my menu, sees that it is not the `MaintenanceController`, and issues a redirect, which goes over and over again. Do you have any idea how can I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly better would also be to use the Configure::read( "System.maintenance" ) or similar. (I tend to namespace my config data, System being the namespace for stuff like maintenance flags etc.)

Also, as Charles said - don't use an error page for an expected event. Errors are to show the user, and for the application to handle notifications etc, about unexpected failures. The maintenance page could simply be a view file in the /app/views/pages/ folder. Redirect to that if the config key is set to true/1.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to be intelligent, but you might be overdoing it a little.

I have a similar setup in a site I am currently developing and I simply use the auth component to take care of it for me.

To help out, I setup a new offline layout that I force the application to use if status of the site is 0 (offline). If the status is 0 app_controller denies access to the entire site.

```
$this->Auth->deny('*');
$this->layout = "offline";
```

Also, in this layout I have a hidden login form that appears if the user clicks the message.If user is able to authenticate (all users for now - development) access is granted to the entire site using the default template.

Check it out, it might help you out...

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718189/cakephp-site-offline-admin-routing-not-working)

Some of the code, but you can read more about it in the link above

```
function beforeFilter(){
// Site Offline = 0 , Site Online = 1
if($this->Configuration->get_site_status() == 1){
      // Allow access to the site to all users and perform all required 
      // beforeFilter code
}else{
    ...
    // If site is OFFLINE but User is logged in allow access. 
    // Later I will need to change it to only allow admin access if logged in as I am still developing
    // Everyone else will be denied access even if they are able to authenticate          
    if(!$this->Auth->user() == null){
        $this->layout = 'default';
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
    }else{        
        $this->layout = 'offline';
        $this->Auth->deny('*');
    }
    ...
  }
}
```